USB-C Port CC Line Pull-Up Resistors
I have a charging system based on the IP3212 (diagram below)

charging will be done via USB Type-C, the current should be within 1.5-3A (depending on the battery that the user puts). I have questions about the pull-up resistor for the CC lines of the port, at first I read that you need to add 5.1K Ohm and that will be enough, but then I decided to look at the datasheet and it says that to get up to 3A (if the unit can give it) you need 10K Ohm resistors, is that true? Perhaps I misunderstood what was written because I am not very strong in English and could possibly misunderstand something.

I also have a question about the DATA lines, do I need to put a resistor for D+ and D-? I use ESP32 and CH340C if you need this information.

And the last thing I'm interested in is the function of the SBU1/2 pin, what role it plays in the port, I could not find exact information by searching on Google. I would be grateful if you could give me some advice.
Thanks in advance!


Your device wants to draw/sink power from the other device.
You don't put pull-ups. That's the job of the power supply side.
You must put the 5k1 pull-downs to present your device as needing power.
Which also means many things.
First of all, you cannot blindly draw 1.5A or 3A because you don't know how much is available.
You can detect how much is available, 900mA, 1.5A, or 3A based on which resistor or voltage the combination of your pull down and supply pull up has.
Otherwise if you plug into a laptop or adapter cable that will support only 900mA, you may damage the port.
And no you don't need resistors for D+/D- pins. The CH340 handles the data pins for you.
The SBU pins are for Side Band Use. If you negotiate a mode which needs them then they must be connected, such as in DP Alt Mode. You don't need them.
Also your schematics may not work well and are not USB compliant. The VGND is not connected anywhere in your circuit, and you can't just put a big 100uF cap onto the VBUS as it violates USB specs.

It turns out that I need to leave the 5.1K pull-ups and I will be able to get 2 or more amperes if the unit implements this, if I set 10K, I can damage something lower-current. It is not worth installing resistors for DATA lines. Regarding the VGND, I will add part of the circuit, this is the input for the MOSFET for protection against reverse polarity, at the output we get a regular GND. I did not know that such a capacitor cannot be installed, which one can be installed then and can you provide more details on why it is not suitable?

@Pisppus The 5k1 resistors are pull-downs, not pull-ups. You cannot put anything else to your device than 5k1 pull-downs in order to be detected as a device requesting power. The pull-ups are on power supply side, indicating how much it can provide, not on your side indicating how much your device wants to consume. Also you can't disconnect VGND with FET. All data lines are referenced to the real GND. So is the metal connector shell. So your FET will already be bypassed with a short circuit over it. Disconnecting ground is a poor idea unfortunately for many reasons.

@Pisppus One more thing, USB defines where the supply and what the polarity is. Why would USB interface even need protection from wrong polarity as it cannot be incorrect?

this is in case you want to power it from a homemade cable that you connect to a power supply, for example, in general it’s not really necessary, but why not install it)

It turns out that it is worth removing the protection here, anyway there is a small risk of incorrect connection, if it is even possible.

@Pisppus Would it not be better to (a) make the homemade cable correctly in case of accidentally plugging it to your phone or laptop and damage it, or (b) not use homemade cables to begin with, as several types of chargers and cables already exist.

Yes, I agree, I didn’t think about what the protection is for, I didn’t even know that the unit itself understands and there are already ready-made cables, an error can’t occur here.

I also wanted to ask about that capacitor, what should I do with it, you wrote that it is not suitable.

@Pisppus Remove it. Max total capacitance at hotplug is 10uF and it must not be exceeded.

5k1 defines the UFP supply limit in Table 7 using pull-down R.  This tells the target that a supply is connected when V is not the same as R pull-up voltage.
Table 6 defines the demand load for DFP using pull-up R tells the supply what to provide.

Table 6 signals how much supply is able to provide as source and the current limit must be obeyed by the sink. Table 7 simply provides the value a sink must have for correct detection for a device being present, before supply even turns the power on.

That doesn't add much to my interpretation of this source/sink DC bias communication nor change my understanding.
